# expl3: fully expand two more arguments

Tags: expl3, expansion

I wish to assign the `\crefname` of a counter `\__my_countername:` according to two related string, and for this I wrote something like:

```
\exp_args:Nx \crefname { \__my_countername: }{ \csname my@cref@\__my_countername: @name\endcsname}{\csname my@cref@\__my_countername: @name@plural\endcsname }
```

However, only the first `\__my_countername:` got expanded. How can I get the other two `\__my_countername:` expand too? I looked into the manual `interface3.pdf` and found that there's no `\exp_args:Nxxx`, also `\exp:w\__my_countername:\exp_end:` doesn't work.

Comment: Instead of `\exp_args:Nx` which will `x`-expand the first argument, use `\exp_args:Nxxx` to `x`-expand three arguments. In `expl3` each letter after the colon represents one argument (exception: low level code using `w`-type arguments). If an `\exp_args:N...` variant doesn't exist yet, you can create it with `\exp_args_generate:n`.

Comment: @Skillmon But then I would get `Undefined control sequence. <argument> \exp_args:Nxxx`, so it seems that `\exp_args:Nxxx` doesn't exist.

Comment: `\exp_args_generate:n { xxx }` and afterwards you can use `\exp_args:Nxxx`.

Comment: @Skillmon Thank you very much, it didn't occurred to me that primitives can also have type variations.

Comment: `\exp_args:N...` is not a primitive, just a cleverly defined macro of `expl3`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, 'ad hoc' expansion is less favoured by `expl3` than having pre-defined functions with the correct signature. As such, the reason you don't find `\exp_args:Nxxx` is that there's nowhere that it's been created by *e.g.*

```latex
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \some_foo:nnn { xxx }
```

However, we can force it to exist using

```latex
\exp_args_generate:n { xxx }
```

I would though not use `x`-type expansion here. You have three arguments, one which claims to be a function-with-no-arguments but I suspect is really a tl var, and two which are tl vars addressed by csname. We therefore want to extract values, which is what `V` and `v` are for:

```latex
\exp_args_generate:n { Vvv }
\exp_args:NVvv \crefname
  \__my_countername:
  { my@cref@\__my_countername: @name }
  { my@cref@\__my_countername: @name@plural }
```

(Once again, this is quite an unusual variant so I've had to create it.)